# BigQuery: "Clustering encountered a key that is longer than"

Tags: google-bigquery, clustered-index

When clustering my Wikipedia pageviews tables I got the error:

> Clustering encountered a key that is longer than the maximum allowed limit of 1024 bytes.

Context: https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

(I'm clustering by

```
CREATE TABLE `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017`
PARTITION BY DATE(datehour)
CLUSTER BY wiki, title
...
```

)

Comment: as FYI : from what I understand  - there is a bug found in enforcing the 1KB length that was introduced recently. So, that is disabled as of now till it is fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When clustering tables BigQuery has a limit of 1KB for the keys.

You can solve this for the example tables by changing your insertion code so it truncates any entry that's too long.

For example, instead of:

```
INSERT INTO `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` (datehour, wiki, title, views)
SELECT datehour, wiki, title, views
```

truncate the potentially long titles with:

```
INSERT INTO `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` (datehour, wiki, title, views)
SELECT datehour, wiki, SUBSTR(title, 0, 300) title, views
```

If you continue to experience errors, note that some malformed strings might have a longer length than what `SUBSTR()` sees. Filter those out with:

```
WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(title) < 300
```

Comment: gotta say I love seeing BQ evolving and innovating at the speed it does :)!

Comment: I suspect it’s not that the title is “malformed”, but hat SUBSTR operates on Unicode runes (characters) and that the clustering limits are in bytes. Thus, titles with double/triple width characters (many Chinese characters, accented characters, emoji) will fall into this case.

Comment: In my specific case, it was malformed strings (coming from real life logs)

Comment: I'm doing `CLUSTER BY wiki, title`, so I had to make sure that `BYTE_LENGTH(wiki+title)` was lower than the limit.

Comment: Do you know if BigQuery is working on extending this limit @FelipeHoffa?

Comment: Just following up on this thread. This limit has been removed for a while now, and the new behavior is documented here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#limitations